# Why is hiding aspects in Neo4j bad?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to understand the best practices for building a neo4j entity considering the best practices mentioned in the following article about the aspect hiding 
https://neo4j.com/blog/dark-side-neo4j-worst-practices/

The following image explains that the performance is better when the "country" property is modeled as a relation to the Person node rather than having it enclosed in the node itself

The emphasis is on the performance improvement when it is modeled as a separate entity for the query which gets the people who live in a specific country.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.assets.neo4j.com/wp-content/uploads/20160223191647/neo4j-data-modeling-hide-concepts.png

Case 1: "country" field is in Person Entity , so the query traverses through both nodes to check whether the country field is the same

Case 2 : "Country" as a separate entity.

I am unable to understand how in Case 2 , the number of checks are lesser.
Please help me . Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 2):

There's a few things going on here that should influence your modeling decision.

Firstly, when we extract out from a field value to a node, we're normalizing the data. Instead of the same values (for example, 'UK') being duplicated for all :Person nodes who live in the UK, we now only have a single :Country node with the 'UK' code, and all person nodes who live there have :LIVES_IN relationships to their country node. So in this aspect, we're avoiding duplication of string data in the database.

Another thing to consider is that in Neo4j, property lookup and filtering is often one of the more expensive operations, so often you can optimize by tweaking your queries and modeling to minimize property lookup and property filtering.

For the first case, we always have to filter all of my friends to get the ones from the desired country. While this won't be a problem with such a small dataset, friends of a single person, when it comes to more complicated queries you may be doing a good amount of property lookup and filtering, which could slow down the query execution.

In the second case, the planner may be able to optimize by matching to the country with an index lookup (on :Country(code)) in addition to the lookup of Stefan's node (and if the planner doesn't do this, we can use planner hints to force it). With the UK country node pre-matched, we can expand the pattern to friends and their country node, which will do an ExpandInto operation into the UK node (or a node hash join, depending on the planner's approach). In either case, the filtering operation doesn't have to do property access at all, it's instead filtering based on our pre-matched UK node (which under-the-hood filters based on the node's graph id), an efficient operation.

You can use PROFILE or EXPLAIN to check on how the planner will execute the query.

Another aspect that isn't directly related to performance is the flexibility and utility you unlock when extracting out entities like this instead of keeping them as property fields.

By extracting out countries to their own nodes, we can now use those nodes in different contexts. While we currently have :LIVED_IN relationships between :Person and :Country nodes, we can now add any other kind of relationship to and from :Country nodes. We could have data like this in the graph:

```
(:Person)-[:TRAVELED_TO]->(:Country)
(:Language)-[:COMMONLY_SPOKEN_IN]->(:Country)
(:State)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(:Country)
```

and more. While we can use these patterns on their own, the real power comes in when we need to include multiple parts into the same pattern, allowing us to have rich context as we query.

For example: "I want to know which friends of mine live in or traveled to a country where Spanish is commonly spoken, and get back the friend and the countries that matched"

```
MATCH (me:Person {name:'InverseFalcon'})-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(friend)-[:LIVES_IN | TRAVELED_TO]->(country:Country)<-[:COMMONLY_SPOKEN_IN]-(:Language {name:'Spanish'})
RETURN friend, collect(country.code) as countries
```

By refactoring our model like this, we avoid the clunkiness of extracting property values and having to use them in subsequent matches (similar to table joins).